# Editing series of files and replacing the variables from list of var

Tags: bash

I am a biologist but know little about linux system.

I have N no of dir (dir1, dir2 .. dirN) with text file xyz.txt in each dir. I want to edit each file with line `"probability = some variable"`. "some variable" should be replaced by corresponding values in a list of N variables, from variable.txt.

variable.txt looks like following:

```
1 23
2 54
3 89
4 102
.
.
.
N 1000
```

Can anyone help me in writing a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
# read variable.txt in an array
arr=( "" )
while read k v; do arr+=( $v ); done < variable.txt

# now start replacing xyz.txt in each subdir
i=1;
while read file; do
   repl=${arr[$i]}
   sed -i.bak "s/\(probability = \)some variable/\1$repl/" "$file"
   i=((i++))
done < <(find /some/path -name "xyz.txt")
```

Comment: Are the double `<` on the last line intentional?

Comment: Yes very much intentional for process output indirection.

Comment: Honestly, I would go for something easier if you want the OP to learn from the answer. This is high-level!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names are known in advance and are suffixed as you describe, you can try the following script

```
while read number prob ;
do
    sed -i.bak "s/probability = .*$/probability = $prob/" dir$number/xyz.txt
done < variable.txt
```

Demo:

```
$ cat t.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while read number prob ;
do
    sed -i.bak "s/probability = .*$/probability = $prob/" dir$number/xyz.txt
done < variable.txt
$ for i in {1..4} ; do cat -n dir$i/xyz.txt;  done
     1  tata
     2  probability = some value
     1  tata
     2  probability = some value
     1  tata
     2  probability = some value
     1  tata
     2  probability = some value
$ cat variable.txt 
1 23
2 54
3 89
4 102
$ ./t.sh 
$ for i in {1..4} ; do cat -n dir$i/xyz.txt;  done
     1  tata
     2  probability = 23
     1  tata
     2  probability = 54
     1  tata
     2  probability = 89
     1  tata
     2  probability = 102
```

Comment: superb........one line script for great monkey job                   Thanks a lot